# Redirect and popup when sql is done

Tags: javascript, php

I want to get my application when a item is deleted pop up a messege and redirect to another page. I used javascipt for the popup and php header for the redirection. Now its only doing or the popup or the redirect depending which one is listed first. how do i fix this?

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('../../includes/mysql_config.php');

$id = isset($_SESSION['id']) ? $_SESSION['id'] : header('location: ../../login.php');
$Cursist = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE id =".$_SESSION['id']);
if(!$Cursist){
  header('location: ../login.php');
}

$test = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "DELETE FROM cursus WHERE id = $test";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if ($result) {
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Verwijdert!')</script>";
  header("Location: ../cursussen.php?destoyed=true&destroyed_id=".$_GET['id']);
}else {
  echo "mislukt";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send sometrhing before header will not work. You can use only header before sending sometrhing to the client.

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

You could do with javascript but It not recommended because the user could have javascript disabled:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "alert('Verwijdert!')";
echo "document.location.href='index.html'";
echo "</script>";
```

The best way is to use session and header, you can save a var in session and show a message when the var is true and when you show the messasge delete the session var

delete.php

```
$_SESSION['deleted'] = true;
header("Location: index.php);
```

index.php

```
<?php if($_SESSION['deleted']){ ?>
<?php unset($_SESSION['deleted']) ?>
<div>Item was deleted</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is that the redirect immediately moves you to a new page, so any javascript on the old page becomes irrelevant.  You might be able to use a delay before redirect so that the javascript alert can display.

Otherwise, introduce a variable that you send to the redirect destination page, and use this variable to trigger a javascript popup there.